# Seeking a (simple) proof that the sphere packing density is always less than $1$ in $n \ge 2$ dimension.

Tags: geometry, analysis, measure-theory, packing-problem

For each natural number $n$, we may define the (optimal) *sphere packing density* in $\Bbb R^n$ to be the number
$$
D_n = \limsup_{r\to\infty} D_n(r),
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
D_n(r) = \sup \Big\{ \frac{k\omega_n}{(2r)^n} :& \text{there exist $a_1,\dots,a_k$ such that $B(a_j)\subset [-r,r]^n$} \\
&\ \  \text{and $B(a_j)$'s are pairwise disjoint} \Big\}.
\end{align}$$

Of course, $B(a)$ denotes the open unit ball centered at $a$, and $\omega_n$ is the $n$-volume of the unit ball in $\Bbb R^n$. I have no idea if this is how the density is normally defined or not, but it should be equivalent to the standard definition nonetheless. My $D_n(r)$ is the maximal density of packing unit balls into an $n$-cube of side length $2r$, and $D_n$ is the limit as the side length  of this cube goes to infinity.

> Is there a relatively simple argument to show that $D_n <1$ for all $n\ge 2$?

I know that calculating $D_n$ precisely is a hard task (except for some very special values of $n$), for example the Kepler conjecture, which says that $D_3 = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}} \simeq 0.7405$, has only been proved in the last ten year, after it had been an open problem for several centuries. I don't need to know that value of $D_n$, I just want to know if it's always bounded away from $1$. While it seems intuitive that we should have $D_n < 1$ always (except for the trivial case $D_1$, where $1$-dimensional balls are just lines), I can't think of a quick proof of it off the top of my head.

It doesn't seem too hard to show that $D_n(r) < 1$ for each fixed $r$ since there is definitely some wasted space between the unit balls, however, I can't think of any a priori reason why there wouldn't be a better and better possible configuration as $r$ grows large that may make $D_n(r)\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$. I am thinking that adapting the proof of Besicovitch covering theorem could do the trick, but I haven't tried writing down the details yet.

I know essentially nothing regarding this topic, so perhaps the answer to my question is already well-known or even a standard result in sphere packing. If so, I would be delighted if anyone could point me to a good resource that discusses this kind of question.

Comment: Here is a proof: Take arbitrary ball $A$ from a covering. It either can be inflated by a coefficient $1+\epsilon$ (with fixing the center) or there is another ball $B$ at the distance less than $\epsilon$. In the latter case, take the hyperplane tangent to $A$ which is perpendicular to the line connecting the centers of $A$ and $B$, the one closer to $B$. Let $C$ be the touching point. There is some $\delta$ such the a ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $C$ has the property that the convex closure of that ball and the center of $A$ intersects only the ball $A$.

Comment: The union of that convex closure and the ball $A$ has a larger and constant volume than $A$. This ball of radius $\delta$, it is a ball within the hyperplane, I forgot to say that. Now you should just pick epsilon and delta for which you can easily prove the claimed claims here, which shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @donaastor I am sorry but I don't quite follow what you were trying to say there. From the first sentence,  what covering were you talking about? In my question I didn't mention any covering at all so I am a bit confused. Could you please explain more what you were trying to do? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. I was talking about arbitrary packing. I accidentaly said covering instead of packing. The idea is to find an extension for each ball such that all extensions don't intersect other balls or other extensions and such that each extension's volume is bounded by below. Taking epsilon and delta both 0.1 enaures that.

Comment: @donaastor It seems like a plausible sketch of proof that could work. Do you propose a quick way to compute your $\delta$ for a given dimension $n$? I don't doubt that it should exist, but it is not trivial (although not necessarily hard) to prove its existence.

Comment: Yes. As I said, $0.1$ will work for both $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. It doesn't depend on $n$

Comment: @donaastor That cannot be. It obviously doesn't work when $n=1$. Also, I still don't know what your $\epsilon$ refers to, you only explained what your $\delta$ means.
Edit: I see what $\epsilon$ is now, sorry about that. I was sleepy when I first read your comment.

Comment: No problem :) And yes, it doesn't work for $n=1$. I was taking your assumption that $n>1$. Then it works. It is easy to prove so I don't want to reveal it to you, but if you ask then I will write out the complete proof tomorrow.

Comment: @donaastor I think the problem was that I read your comment at 3 a.m. last night so I misunderstood a portion of it. I haven't done any work regarding this yet (including the sketch that I have in mind) but I don't doubt that it can be done, especially if you claim it's simple. Your idea, as I understand it, seems valid enough, provided that $\delta$ doesn't shrink as $n\to\infty$. I think we can even discard $\epsilon$ altogether.

Comment: I agree. $\epsilon$ could be discarded. But then we should pay more attention on choosing the ball $B$. It should be the closest one to $A$. Then we can really discard $\epsilon$.

Comment: @donaastor Well, since you already thought of an answer anyway, why not write it down so I can accept it (an for others in the future who may be interested in the details)? I'd like to see your derivation of the number $0.1$ as well, since I'd probably arrive at a different number when I try to do it later.